# Migrate tabular environment from beamer to article with floating support

Tags: tables, verbatim

I take the `\newenvironment{exampletwoup}` from [here](https://github.com/kks32/writing-thesis-effectively/blob/master/preamble.tex) used in a beamer class and I would like to use in a article class. Is not working with a image.

```
% !TeX document-id = {9c92a2d6-aec3-419c-9803-7504f4517d84}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///lualatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minted}

\newenvironment{exampletwoup}
{\VerbatimEnvironment
    \begin{VerbatimOut}{example1.out}}
    {\end{VerbatimOut}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}{l|l}
            \begin{minipage}{0.35\paperwidth}
                \inputminted[fontsize=\small,resetmargins]{latex}{example1.out}
            \end{minipage} &
            \begin{minipage}{0.3\paperwidth}
                \input{example1.out}
            \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{exampletwoup}
\begin{itemize}
\item Tea
\item Milk
\item Biscuits
\end{itemize}
\end{exampletwoup}
\vskip 2ex
\begin{exampletwoup}
\begin{equation}
\alpha + \beta + 1
\end{equation}
\end{exampletwoup}
\vskip 2ex
\begin{exampletwoup}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\end{exampletwoup}
\vskip 2ex
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm lost with this error. Please, could you tell me any suggestion?

```
(./_minted-main2/CAFE693B42EA6E7531C83238BFBD4D9B3A17687B8B939E33FC53AC4D620A05
FD.pygtex) (./example1.out

! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

Comment: delete `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` you can not have a figure in a box

Comment: Works, thank you. Closing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% !TeX document-id = {9c92a2d6-aec3-419c-9803-7504f4517d84}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///lualatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{minted}

\newenvironment{exampletwoup}
{\VerbatimEnvironment
    \begin{VerbatimOut}{example1.out}}
    {\end{VerbatimOut}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}{l|l}
            \begin{minipage}{0.35\paperwidth}
                \inputminted[fontsize=\small,resetmargins]{latex}{example1.out}
            \end{minipage} &
            \begin{minipage}{0.3\paperwidth}
                \input{example1.out}
            \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{exampletwoup}
\begin{itemize}
\item Tea
\item Milk
\item Biscuits
\end{itemize}
\end{exampletwoup}
\vskip 2ex
\begin{exampletwoup}
\begin{equation}
\alpha + \beta + 1
\end{equation}
\end{exampletwoup}
\vskip 2ex
\begin{exampletwoup}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}
\end{exampletwoup}
\vskip 2ex

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]